# Change column name when export to excel in php

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

Following is my code which export excel sheet on button press.

I deleted some code for privacy. so if there is a mistake of some commas or anything that is missing that you found so ignore that. Thanks

```
if(isset($_POST['export']))
{
 $filename = "DEVICE_OUTPUT_DETAIL_$dvc.csv";
 $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
 $query = "SELECT `DATE`,`DC_VOLTAGE`,`DC_CURRENT`,`PVPANEL_KWH`,`PUMP_AMP`,`PUMP_VOLTAGE`,`PUMP_KW`,`PUMP_FREQ`
   FROM wp_inverterdata where DEVICE_ID = '$dvccid'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

for($i=0;$i<=7;$i++)
{
    $header[] = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
}

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
fputcsv($fp, $header);

$query12 = "SELECT 
`DATE`,`DC_VOLTAGE`,`DC_CURRENT`,`PVPANEL_KWH`,`PUMP_AMP`,`PUMP_VOLTAGE`,`PUMP_KW`,`PUMP_FREQ`
 FROM wp_inverterdata device_id = '$dvccid'";
$result12 = mysql_query($query12);

while($row12 = mysql_fetch_row($result12)) {
  fputcsv($fp, $row12);
}
exit;
}
```

This Code working perfectly.but the problem is in the page where data shown I use **"Motor"** word instead of **"PUMP"** in table heading. but in database column name starts with PUMP.
So is there any way to change column name  MOTOR instead of PUMP in Excel.

For Example above code gives me output like this
[image]
So Can I Change Column Name which I get in this excel using PHP?

Comment: `select old_column_name as new_column_name, ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change column in select query by putting eg. 'DATE' **as date**

```
$query = "SELECT `DATE` as date,`DC_VOLTAGE` as DCVOLT,`DC_CURRENT` as DCCurr,`PVPANEL_KWH`,`PUMP_AMP`,`PUMP_VOLTAGE`,`PUMP_KW` as MotorKW,`PUMP_FREQ` as MotorFREQ 
   FROM wp_inverterdata where DEVICE_ID = '$dvccid'";
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks.it quite nice solution.data also shown but with error of "undefined headers" and putcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array

Comment: try fputcsv($fp, explode(',',$header)); this one pass $header as array

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make the titles of your excel differ from your database column names then you can just use the `AS` statement in your SQL query, which is a Alias for Example

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name AS alias_name;
```

So when you create your report you will have what you want.
Hope this helps